# Get text of input elements selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

The html part that I am interested in like that

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <select ng-show="ReadOnly != true" ng-model="SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
                                    <option value="0" ng-selected="gov.Id == 0"></option>
                                    <!-- ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:1">القاهرة</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:2">الإسكندرية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:3">بورسعيد</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:4">السويس</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:11">دمياط</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:12">الدقهلية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:13">الشرقية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:14">القليوبية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:15">كفر الشيخ</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:16">الغربية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:17">المنوفية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:18">البحيرة</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:19">الاسماعيلية</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:21">الجيزة</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:22">بنى سويف</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:23">الفيوم</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:24">المنيا</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:25">اسيوط</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:26">سوهاج</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:27">قنا</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:28">أسوان</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:31">البحر الاحمر</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:32">الوادي الجديد</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:33" selected="selected">مطروح</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:34">شمال سيناء</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:35">جنوب سيناء</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs --><option ng-repeat="gov in Govs" ng-value="gov.Id" ng-selected="gov.Id == SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:36">الاقصر</option><!-- end ngRepeat: gov in Govs -->
                                </select>
                                <div class="form-control ng-hide" ng-show="ReadOnly == true">Matruh</div>
                            </div>
```

And I have used these lines in python selenium

```
for inputElement in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="form-control ng-hide"]'):
    print(inputElement.text)
```

But I got blank strings as a return. I expected for the html part for example to get `Matruh`

I couldn't post the html source of the iframe I am working on directly here
Here's a link of a text file of the html source
https://anonfiles.com/l8M0n533ud/HTML_txt

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one element then why `find_elements` ?

use this :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.form-control.ng-hide").text)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.form-control.ng-hide"))).text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There are similar elements that I need. Generally, I got blank string too when trying css_selector.

Comment: did you try with above one ? if that does not work, there should be appropriate exception

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution and doesn't work for me.

Comment: I would like to know what error it threw ?

Comment: No errors but I didn't get the expected text.

Comment: I tried the update and I got `TimeoutException: Message: `. The element is already visible but I think it is updated by javascript. This may be the reason.

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: It is part of a private website that requires credentials.

Comment: can you send me page resource  ?

Comment: I have put a link in the main question.

Comment: I am not able to download that text file

Comment: Here's a nother link https://www.mediafire.com/file/5938ccci7otc66d/HTML.txt/file

Comment: can you try this xpath : - `//input[contains(@class, 'ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid')]/following-sibling::div`

Comment: Thank you very much. This doesn't get the text too (I am lost in fact). I tried to find such xpath `//select[contains(@ng-model,'SaveModel.Address_GOV_Code')]/following-sibling::div` and this selects the line that has the text but returns empty string in the code.